# R.color displaying wrong data

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm getting some strange behaviour while getting the stored color value from resource. I have created a file named v_color.xml in values folder.

```
     <resources>
     <color name="Blue_ICS">#000099CC</color>
     </resources>
```

whose decimal value should be = 39372. But when i'm putting this in log,

```
Log.e(TAG, "Color="+R.color.Blue_ICS);
```

im getting value Color=2131296268. So can anyone tell,where i'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking the pointer.

Use

```
Log.e(TAG, "Color="+getResources().getColor(R.color.Blue_ICS));
```